# Excel : why is this simple conditional formatting not working?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

In the column are the calendar week number.
I want the current week to be hilghlighted.

Here the formula in English ist =WEEKNUM(TODAY();2)
**We are in week 21, why is the week 18 green when it should remains white ?**

[image]
Thanks !

Comment: Your formula should be comparing the cell value to the result of your current formula: `=B3=WEEKNUM(TODAY();2)`

Comment: Sorry, I updated the screenshot

Comment: @Rory Also applied range would be cells, containing week numbers. OP uses only `B3` as applies to range.

Answer (score 0):

Applies to range shouldn't be only `B3` for your case. Try as per below screenshot.

```
=$B3=WEEKNUM(TODAY();2)
```

[image]